# JavaScript find in array and replace one value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm struggling with some simple javascript code.
I have some e-commerce project that is made in Vue, and I want to choose variants on client-side. So I'm sending data to the backend in that format:

```
{
    "options": [
        {
            "key": "Size",
            "value": "L"
        },
        {
            "key": "Color",
            "value": "Green"
        }
    ]
}
```

And backend is returning the price of selected options, and the id of the product is getting from the link. So I'm doing a push to array on my frontend like so:

```
getVariationPrice(id, attr, value){
            this.variation.options.push({
                    key: attr,
                    value: value
        });
```

id is product id from URL.

So I'm listing attributes for that product like so:

```
 <span v-for="(attributes, index) in product.attributes" :key="index">
         {{ attributes.key }}
    <v-chip-group active-class="deep-purple accent-4 white--text" column>
       <span v-for="(values, vIndex) in attributes.values" :key="vIndex">
         <v-chip  @click="getVariationPrice(product.id, attributes.key, values)">{{ values }}</v-chip>
       </span>
    </v-chip-group>
  </span>
```

As you see I have getVariationPrice function in it.
So question is, how to make these values replaceable? Because every time when I select a new value, it's pushing to array and send incorrect data to the backend.

PS: Have in mind that backend could return different attributes, not only size and color, but it will check every given value and search that product, it must return only selected keys and values.

Comment: pass the indexes, update `product.attributes[index].values[vIndex]` instead

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `v-model` in `v-chip-group` which is supported in vuetify.

```
<v-chip-group v-model="attributes.values" multiple></v-chip-group>
```

And assign value to each chip

You don't need to call a function when the mouse is clicked. `v-model` handles the `attributes.values` automatically.

Hope this is helpful

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working as I need like so :)